# scale up/down slurm cluster

Tags: openstack, slurm, heat

I just started learning slurm, heat recently and I have got some questions.

I have an existing slurm cluster created using ansible and heat. Heat creates the cluster and ansible just installs/configures all the necessary software on all nodes.

Now I wanted to add new compute nodes to the existing cluster. I have tried 'openstack update' command, but it will rebuild all the existing nodes. Is there an appropriate way to add new compute nodes without rebuilding the existing ones?

I also looked at autoscaling based on cpu usage using ceilometer. This seems working but without restarting slurm, how to let existing nodes in slurm cluster know that there're new compute nodes added? Is that possible to modify slurm.conf, slurmdbd.conf, /etc/hosts, knownhosts etc without restarting?

The goal is when cpu usage reaches certain level, silently add new compute nodes and configure them to be part of the existing cluster.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

That's the one of limitation in slurm, modifying the config file OR adding new node should definitely required the rest of slurm daemons or reload of slurmctld daemon to read the new configuration changes you made .

Just In case slurm.conf are stored on NFS centralized, reloading of controller daemon is good  but you may see some warnings from other nodes